# Advanced Queries in EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql

I have a main table for gather Real Estate records. This table has relations with other reference data tables, so in summary it contains IDs for:

- CountryId
- TypeId
- PurposeId
- CurrencyId
- etc...

There are other tables like Countries, Types, Purposes, etc ...

When creating a new Real Estate record, based on the "Type", there are some "Extended Properties" defined. So user has to enter values for those "Extended Properties" that are directly linked to the selected "Type".

An example of Extended Property something as:

- Bedrooms

This property might have 1 or more values like:

- 1
- 2
- 3

I am storing a table of Extended Properties and another for Extended Property Values, as one Property might have one or more values.

For a given Type, there might be one or more such properties, hence I had to define a new table to link:

- RealEstate ID
- ExtendedProperty ID
- ExtendedProperty Value ID

Now, the website offers a search engine, user can enter search criteria for the following fields:

- Country
- Type
- Purpose
- One or more Extended Property (based on the Type selected and its related Properties)

I need to query the DB and return full data records, i.e. When I return a Real Estate record, I need to return the TypeID + TypeName and CountryID + CountryName, etc ... In other words, I need to join all those tables and then query with the values I received from the search criteria, and such a criteria can be something as:

- CountryId = 1
- Type = 2
- EP (1,5) (Find me a Real Estate record that has an Extended Property whose ID is "1" and has a value for that property equal to Extended Property Value ID of "5".
- etc ...

I believe, all other tables, its a matter of normal join and checking on some parameters, but its gets harder when I have to query the Extended Properties.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to write this as a LINQ expression, or as T-SQL? Your tags are confusing, and the text in your question does not resolve that confusion.

Comment: I haven't got time to get into this now but it may help you to know (if you didn't yet) that the "Extended Properties" part of your model is known as "entity attribute value" (eav). You should be able to find sql/ef examples of that.

Comment: Still waiting for an answer. Thanks